# How to access the ActiveMQ "Classic" statistics plugin in Python

Tags: python, statistics, activemq-classic

I referred to the [ActiveMQ "Classic" documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) to get statistics of broker/queues. This stats is needed to create some analysis. I tried as mentioned in the attached link but not able to fetch the stats with following code snippet. I see messages in **ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker** queue but none in **test** queue.

Code snippet::

```
self.conn = stomp.Connection([('localhost', 61616)] , keepalive=True, try_loopback_connect=True, reconnect_attempts_max=3,)
self.conn.set_listener("testlistener", TestListener(print_to_log=True))
# couple of more listeners for some existing purpose




def retrieve_stats(self) -> None:
  print("*************START*****************\n")

  self.conn.subscribe(id=time.time(), destination="/queue/test") # created a new queue where stats can be pushed

  self.conn.send(
      body="",
      destination="/queue/ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker",
      content_type="text/blah",
      headers={
          "amq-msg-type": "text",
          "persistent": "true",
          "reply-to": "/queue/test",
        },
  )
  broker_stat_listener = self.conn.get_listener("testlistener")
  if len(broker_stat_listener.message_list) > 0:
       print(broker_stat_listener.message_list.__str__())

  print("*************END*****************\n")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbaPS.png)

Comment: Please add some examples of what have you tried so far.

Comment: What protocol are you using from your Python application?

Comment: Hi Justin, it's STOMP protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, Python is using STOMP protocol. Simply setup the statistics broker plugin on the server-side, then send the messages to the specially named queues, and subscribe to the response queues to get the output.

ref: [Example python + stomp listener](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/blob/dev/tests/test_activemq.py)

Comment: Thanks Matt Pavlovich. Yes Stomp protocol is the one that we use to send message to ActiveMq. As far as I understand, you mean to create a listener. correct? if you can point me to some code snippet, it would be helpful

Comment: Yep! Check this out: https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/blob/dev/tests/test_activemq.py

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the guidance so far. I have edited the question description with the code snippet. It will be helpful if you can have a look, as I am not able to get the stats

Comment: @KhushbooSingh full code review is outside scope of what can reasonably be accomplished on SO. I suggest confirming you have the StatisticsBrokerPlugin working using the ActiveMQ console, by sending a message and seeing the response show up in the ReplyTo queue. Once that works, adapt your code and you should be good!